# How to get editors for google docs using google api scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

How to list editors for google doc file using google api script? I have tried this.

```
var fileEditors=someGoogleDoc.getEditors();
```

This code always results into null array. I want list of editors as array.

Comment: For example, if `someGoogleDoc` is `var someGoogleDoc = DocumentApp.openById(id)`, I think that `fileEditors` shows an array including owner's email address. But in your question, you say `This code always results into null array.`. So can you provide the script for replicating your issue? By this, we would like to confirm about your issue and think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#geteditors and add a [mcve].